# How make the colors more in line with the legend when using position_identity in geom_col?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am drawing this graph below and I want to show the differences in annual growth between gross income and net income for different social classes. As you can see when gross and net income go in different directions as in the case of the low-skilled working class, the colors match the legend. However, if annual growth go in the same direction as in the case of the first three bars, then we see growth income in red, and net income in orange. Is there a way to keep the colors contrasting as in the last column on the right even when they overlap?

Here is the graph:

[image]

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=year, y=annual_chg, fill=income,color=income)) +
  geom_col(position = "identity", alpha = 1/2,colour= "black") +  
  facet_wrap(~Class,nrow=1)+
  theme_classic()+xlab(NULL)+ylab(NULL)+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue4","red4"))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue4","red4"))
```

Here is the data:

```
df= structure(list(year = c(2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
    2018), annual_chg = c(-0.66, 0.34, 0.59, 1.54, -0.26, 0.49, 0.66, 
    1.62), Class = structure(c(4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Upper-middle class", 
    "Middle class", "Skilled working class", "Low-skilled working class"
    ), class = "factor"), income = c("gross income", "gross income", 
    "gross income", "gross income", "net income", "net income", "net income", 
    "net income")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
    "data.frame"))
```

**Edit 21 March 2022**

The code suggested by @Jon Spring works well for some cases in my data. But in other cases it does not. These are: 1) when there are negative values (see **L** column in **FR**, or 2) in case of gross income is larger than net income (see all columns in **ES**), or 3) in case gross income is positive and net income is negative or vice versa (see columns **S** and **M** in **FR**). I upload a new data that shows better where these cases do not work out well (see below the data).

Here is the graph i get using the recommended code:
[image]

Since the data changed, I changed the code accordingly but it has the same logic of the recommended code:

```
    df %>%
group_by(class,cntry) %>%
  arrange(abs(annual_chg)) %>%
  mutate(increm = annual_chg - lag(annual_chg, default = 0)) %>%
  mutate(class = forcats::fct_rev(class)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=class, y=increm, fill=income, color=income)) +
  geom_col(position = "stack", alpha = 1/2, color = "black") +  
  facet_wrap(~cntry,nrow=1)+
  theme_classic()+ xlab(NULL)+ ylab(NULL)+
  #scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::breaks_width(1)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue4","red4"))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue4","red4"))
```

Here are the details where the code does not work which I discussed above. For example, in the group **L** in **FR**, both values are negative for annual change, the conversion is correct. But on the graph, net income (the blue part) should precede gross income in that column, otherwise it gives the impression that net income is larger which is not the case. A second example is for the group **S**, since the growth in `net income` is positive and `gross income` is negative, the values should have remained the same. But as you can see below this is not the case, the conversion between `annual_chg` and `increm` remained the same for `net income` (`0.192`) but not for `gross income` where it there was a conversion from `-0.215` to `-0.407`. The same goes for the category `M`.

```
  class annual_chg cntry income       increm
  <fct>      <dbl> <fct> <fct>         <dbl>
1 M         -0.129 FR    gross income -0.129
2 L         -0.145 FR    net income   -0.145
3 U          0.188 FR    gross income  0.188
4 S          0.192 FR    net income    0.192
5 S         -0.215 FR    gross income -0.407
6 M          0.395 FR    net income    0.524
7 U          0.613 FR    net income    0.426
8 L         -0.617 FR    gross income -0.472
```

Here is the code that shows the graph with the correct conversion but wrong colors:

```
 df%>%
  mutate(class = forcats::fct_rev(class)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=class, y=annual_chg, fill=income,color=income)) +
  geom_col(position = "identity", alpha = 0.7) +  
  facet_wrap(~cntry,nrow=1)+
  theme_classic()+xlab(NULL)+ylab(NULL)+
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("blue4", "red4")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue4", "red4"))
```

However, again as my initial post above, if you run this code, you can see that the colors do not converge as plain blue and plain red as I want them to be. The code of this plot is similar to the first graph plotted in this post using the `alpha` function. My aim is to get the same graph but just with plain colors without the `alpha` option.

Here is the new data:

```
  df=  structure(list(class = structure(c(4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("U", "M", "S", 
"L"), class = "factor"), annual_chg = c(-0.1451, 0.1921, 0.395, 
0.6132, 1.6244, 1.1252, 2.7932, 1.4609, -0.2693, 0.4774, 0.6305, 
1.517, 1.4667, 1.3716, 1.7485, 1.3212, 0.4443, 0.4652, 1.0318, 
1.0972, 4.9134, 4.4947, 4.3977, 3.2674, -0.6172, -0.2152, -0.1289, 
0.1876, 1.6671, 1.3714, 3.5708, 2.3156, -0.6477, 0.3361, 0.5649, 
1.4651, 0.9387, 0.806, 1.4959, 1.0785, 0.1942, 0.2498, 0.8577, 
0.9915, 4.6258, 3.6042, 4.1313, 2.6896), cntry = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("DE", 
"ES", "FR", "PL", "UK", "US"), class = "factor"), income = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("net income", 
"gross income"), class = "factor")), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -48L), groups = structure(list(
    cntry = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("DE", 
    "ES", "FR", "PL", "UK", "US"), class = "factor"), class = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("U", "M", "S", 
    "L"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(c(12L, 36L
    ), c(11L, 35L), c(10L, 34L), c(9L, 33L), c(8L, 32L), c(7L, 
    31L), c(6L, 30L), c(5L, 29L), c(4L, 28L), c(3L, 27L), c(2L, 
    26L), c(1L, 25L), c(24L, 48L), c(23L, 47L), c(22L, 46L), 
        c(21L, 45L), c(16L, 40L), c(15L, 39L), c(14L, 38L), c(13L, 
        37L), c(20L, 44L), c(19L, 43L), c(18L, 42L), c(17L, 41L
        )), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", 
    "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: Could using `position = "dodge"` resolve this?

Comment: Or more accurately, `position = "stack"`

Comment: I presume the other criterion is that you want both bars to start at 0?

Comment: If you really need these to be separate, you should probably draw each piece separately. Othwerise I don't know how you'd put into a legend that one group overlaps another without having anything in your data that actually indicates that

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I acually i just realized that both "stack" and "dodge" do not work. The former put them next to each other which is not what I am interested in, the latter put them one on top of the other which confuses things as you cannot compare which income growth is larger or smaller

Comment: @camille i am not sure i understood what you meant. The problem is that the legend shows two colors, but the graph I plotted above has three colors. Would you know how to get around that?

Comment: The graph doesn't actually have 3 colors—it has 2 colors corresponding to 2 categories. The fact that you see a 3rd color is because of the overlapping shapes with low alpha. If you want to actually have a 3rd color, you need a 3rd category in your data. That said, as far as a successful data visualization, you really should consider dodging the bars because that will make it easier to see where the different values are coming from exactly

Comment: Thanks for the response, i actually do not want to see a third color. I want to see blue instead of orange for the first three categories while still seeing the red part. Because if I remove the alpha, we just see the color that is larger without seeing anything else. But perhaps this is just not possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the simplest way to do this is to plot the largest bars (be they positive or negative), *then* the smallest bars.

To do this, we create a new variable called `plotting_order`, which chooses the largest absolute value of `net` and `gross` at each point:

```r
plot_df <- df %>%
  mutate(class = forcats::fct_rev(class)) %>%
  group_by(class, cntry) %>%
  mutate(plotting_order = order(abs(annual_chg)))
```

Now the trick is to draw the two layers separately, each one getting its data from the appropriate subset of the `plot_df`

```r
ggplot(aes(class, annual_chg, fill = income, color = income)) +
  geom_col(width = 1, data = plot_df[plot_df$plotting_order == 2,]) +
  geom_col(width = 1, data = plot_df[plot_df$plotting_order == 1,]) +
  facet_wrap( ~ cntry, nrow = 1) +
  theme_classic() +
  xlab(NULL) + 
  ylab(NULL) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#9d9ece", "#ce9e9d")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue4", "red4"))
```

[image]

Note that to keep the bar colors constant, you should keep the alpha at 1 (default)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to modify the data so that when we see a comparatively larger value, the *delta* should be plotted but not the part that overlaps with the smaller value it supercedes.

I'd do this by pre-processing the data first to find the deltas so we can plot those instead of the original values.

```
library(dplyr); library(forcats); library(ggplot2)
df %>%
  group_by(Class, year) %>%
  arrange(abs(annual_chg)) %>%
  mutate(increm = annual_chg - lag(annual_chg, default = 0)) %>%
  mutate(income = forcats::fct_rev(income)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%

ggplot(aes(x=year, y=increm, fill=income, color=income)) +
  geom_col(position = "stack", alpha = 1/2, color = "black") +  
  facet_wrap(~Class,nrow=1)+
  theme_classic()+ xlab(NULL)+ ylab(NULL)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::breaks_width(1)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue4","red4"))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue4","red4"))
```

[image]

Comment: I was reworking on the code now and I just noticed that it works well for the first three columns, but it does not for the last one (Low-skilled working class). My guess is because the values are negative. Is there a way to get around it?